# Trigonometric equation $3\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(3x)=3\sin x\cdot\sin^2(3x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Number of real solution of the equation $\displaystyle \sin^2(x)+\frac{1}{3}\sin^2(3x)=\sin(x)\cdot\sin^2(3x)$ in $x\in[0,2\pi]$

Put $\sin^2(x)=a$ and $\sin^2(3x)=b$ then $\displaystyle a+\frac{b}{3}=ab^2$

$3a+b=3ab^2$ Help me how to solve

Comment: Use $\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $s=\sin x$. Then $\sin 3x=3s-4s^4$. Your original equation is
$$3s^2+(3s-4s^3)^2=3s(3s-4s^3)^2$$
which simplifies to
$$s^2(-12+27s+24s^2-72s^3-16s^4+48s^5)=0.$$
Numerical investigation suggests the bracket is nonzero on $[-1,1]$
so that $s=0$, or $x=n\pi$ ($n$ integer) is the only solution.